# Visual Studio: MyMacros won't show up in Tools > Options > Environ. > keyboard

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, macros

I have a macro that I wrote to just help me with my unit testing (it was derived from other macros that just add underscores to the name of the method as you write it,), and when I go to Tool > Options > Environment > and then keyboard to assign a shortcut to it, it not anywhere to be found, none of the "MyMacros" default section is there. Any ideas?

Also, the macro explorer option isn't under Tools menu, I need to hit ALT+F8 to get to it, maybe they are related?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely running into an issue where your current profile settings hid the macro explorer.  Try going to Tools -> Import/Export Settings and choose reset all settings.  Choose the "General Profile."  If it is a settings issue, this will cause the menu to re-appear.